# Schedule powershell script task doesn't Send-MailMessage

Tags: powershell, scheduled-task

I am building a Powershell script to create a company synchronized email signature so I don't have to ask users to manually edit theirs when information changes. It is set up to grab the contents of the signature template file in the shared network drive and combine it with the personal signature located locally on each machine.

My idea was to run this is a scheduled task in an effort to have these updated no later than 24 hours after any potential changes in the template.

If the script fails, it writes to a log and ultimately emails me so I immediately can remedy any problems on a per user basis.

The script runs perfectly, as is, assuming I run it manually .  If I run it as a scheduled task in the user's context (still me), it doesn't send the email notification.

I'll link the script, but what about the scheduled task would cause it to behave differently when it comes to the Send-MailMessage?

My environment is a Server 2008r2 domain running on Windows 7 clients.

```
    ##############################################
    #Script to automatically sync email signatures
    ##############################################

    #Get logged in user - e.g. DOMAIN\user
    $user = $(Get-WMIObject -class Win32_ComputerSystem | select username).username
    #Strip off DOMAIN\
    $user = $user.Substring(8)

    #Define local and network file paths
    $templatePath = "\\files\z\Email Signatures"
    $localPath = "C:\Signature"

    #Grab date last modified for signature template file
    $signatureTemplate = Get-Item -LiteralPath "$templatePath\signature.html"
    $templateLastMod = $signatureTemplate.lastWriteTime.toString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") -as [int64]

    #Grab date last modified for user's current signature
    If((Test-Path "$localPath\$user-signature.html") -eq $true){
        $currentSig = Get-Item -LiteralPath "$localpath\$user-signature.html"
        $currentSigLastMod = $currentSig.lastWriteTime.toString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") -as [int64]
    }
    Else{
        $currentSigLastMod = 00000000
    }

    #If template is newer than signature, generate updated signature
    If ($currentSigLastMod -lt $templateLastMod) {

        $sigPath = "$localPath\$user-signature.html"
        $userInfo = "$localPath\$user.html"

        #If user info doesn't exists, end script
        If ((Test-Path $userInfo) -eq $false) {
            $errorTime = (Get-Date)
            Add-Content "$templatePath\userlog.txt" "$errorTime -- $user.html file for user $user does not exist.  Unable to sync signature file."

            #Set SMTP capable user to send email notification
            $smtpUser = "domain\smtpuser"
            $PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "password" -AsPlainText -Force
            $Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $smtpUser, $PWord

            $emailSmtpServer = "mail.domain.com"
            $emailFrom = "noreply@domain.com"
            $emailTo = "admin@domain.com"
            $emailSubject = "Missing personal info: $user"
            $emailBody = "$errorTime -- $user.html file for user $user does not exist.  Unable to sync signature file."

            Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $emailSmtpServer -Credential $Credential -From $emailFrom -To $emailTo -Subject $emailSubject -Body $emailBody  

            return 
        }
        Else{
            #If current signature already exists, delete it.
            If ((Test-Path $sigPath) -eq $true) {
                Remove-Item -LiteralPath $sigPath
            }
        }

        #Create new signature for user
        New-Item -Path "$localPath" -name "$user-signature.html" -itemtype file 

        #Concatenate template content and user personal info into new signature
        Add-Content "$localPath\$user-signature.html" (Get-Content $signatureTemplate)
        Add-Content "$localPath\$user-signature.html" (Get-Content $userInfo)

    }
    Else {
        return
    }
```

Comment: Try without the credential logic as it will impersonate you.

Comment: I assume I require this since our smtp requires authentication.  Regardless, without it, the behavior does not change

Comment: it is being run in the logged in user's context.

Comment: Put the whole script into a try/catch and in the catch have it write out the $error object to a file.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be producing any errors.  It appears to successfully run each time.  Even if I isolate the try/catch to the Send-MailMessage, it still doesn't produce any errors.

Comment: add the `-ErrorAction Stop` param to the smtp message

Comment: I added this in when I applied the try/catch.  Even with that, it doesn't show any signs of error in the process.  It still continues through to the end.  I added another line immediately following the email that outputs a message to the log letting me know that it didn't exit after the Send-MailMessage command

Comment: There's likely an somewhere in the execution before that line.  I suspect it has something to do with everything going on with the credential.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31721/discussion-between-moosebalm-and-colyn1337).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution Just adding  `Start-Sleep -Seconds 1` as the last line and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Can confirm that adding `Start-Sleep -Seconds 1` to my script also solved the problem in my case. Been scratching my head about this issue for a few hours today. I tried the usual stuff:

- Installed latest Windows Management Framework 5.1
- Disabled Firewall
- Nslookup / ping was working towards the domain
- Some Windows 7 / 2008 instances was working, but some were not for unknown reasons.
- Windows 10 clients has no problems using the same powershell script / network

Putting a `Start-sleep -Seconds 1` before my `Send-Mailmessage` solved my problem.